# Zip Files in .Net 4.5 without 3rd party libraries

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, zip, php-ziparchive

I have a windows form (made with vb) where the business user can enter document numbers in a multi line textbox, each number can have one to many documents under that number i.e. if they enter 12345 then the gridview will display the 4 documents (the name of the documents and the description) that correspond to that document number.

Now I figured out how to parse the document numbers since if they want to enter more than one they need to separate by a comma (thanks to stackoverflow :D!) so I have this list of document names and I have searched this site but I cant understand how to loop through that list of document names from my directory and zip them to a folder without 3rd party libraries like dotnet etc since I am not allowed.

I know about .NET's static (? not sure if the right term) class "zipfile" and "ziparchive" with system.IO and system.IO.compression but looking at the msdn website and answers on here I found answers relating to writing lines in a file to add to a zipfile folder or creating them in the folder.

So my question is, is there anyway where I can loop through that list of document names and create a zipfile folder and add them to the created zipfile folder? So far I got this far in regards to zip paths I got the document name and path for each "file" in the list shown below( which I talked about above):

```
Dim values As String = TextBox1.Text.Replace(" ", ",")
Dim DocNum As String() = values.Trim().Split(","c)
Dim fullitems As String
For Each s As String In DocNum
  Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles("\\folder path" & s)
          If files.Length > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To files.Length - 1
                fullitems = files(i).ToString
            Next i
        End If
  Next
```

Any advice or direction on how to go in adding documents from a folder to a zipfile folder in .net with vb is appreciated!

Comment: `without 3rd party libraries like dotnet` that's not third party it's part of 4.5 framework. If that's the case then write your own compression algorithm, it would be a start...

Comment: @Zaggler thank you for replying! but from what I read I need to download dotnetziplibrary to use it? I tried writing my own algorithm but I am stumped on how to add files in a zip archive or zip file I can only find how to create an entry and write it in it or write in a existing file

Comment: So you want to `add` to an archive ***or*** do you want to `create` a zip file with files, which one?

Comment: @Zappler I apologize for the confusion, I want to create a zip folder and add existing files (in this case documents) to the .zip folder, is that possible?

Comment: Ok, so you want to create a new `zip` and add files to it if I am correct?

Comment: @Zaggler yes! exactly, thank you so much for helping me I'm gonna try out your example and let you know how it goes! thank you again. edit: I'm sorry quick question how can I incorporate multiple files? would I keep my code above then reference it in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I want to create a zip folder and add existing files (in this case documents) to the .zip folder, is that possible?**

Yes it is possible. First you need to add a few references to your project.

- **System.IO.Compression**
- **System.IO.Compression.FileSystem**

Next, add these `Import` statements to your class file.

```
 Imports System.IO
 Imports System.IO.Compression
```

I used a button click event to do this, but you can put anywhere you would like to...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using modFile As ZipArchive = ZipFile.Open("ZIP PATH HERE", ZipArchiveMode.Update)
            modFile.CreateEntryFromFile("FILE YOU WANT TO ADD", "ENTRY NAME")
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: thank you it worked! but the files added in the zip file arent the PDFs they just say "file" and dont open is there anyway to actually copy the pdfs to the zip?

Comment: @jean55 interesting as I worked with some text documents and worked just fine. It should add the file (compressed) to the `zip` file... Let me try on my end with `pdf`...

Comment: @jean55 where it say's `ENTRY NAME` did you make sure to include the file's `extention`? For example: `.pdf`

Comment: @jean55 I could confirm this. If you do not include the extension it will create a blank file. You need to make sure to include the file extention as mentioned above...

Answer (score 0):

For simpler use, if you desire to zip all the files contained in an existing folder.

This is simpler because you do not have to ensure the full filename is specified, it just takes all files found in a folder.  You do have to specify the ".zip" extension on the "destination_file.zip" file name, though.

As indicated in another answer, you need to add two references to your project.

1. System.IO.Compression
2. System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

And add these Import statements to your class file.

```
 Imports System.IO
 Imports System.IO.Compression
```

Here is some code in a button click routine, it can be put elsewhere.  As you can see, it is just one line of code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("Folder you want to zip",
                                "destination_file.zip",
                                 CompressionLevel.Optimal,
                                 False)
End Sub
```

But it appears you wish to send selected files to a .zip archive.

Let's say you have a DataGridView control named *dgv1*, populated with several lines of data and you have multi-selected a few of those lines, and the full path/file name is in the first column of the DataGridView.

There is a helper function (*selectedList()*) to format the selected cells from the datagridview into a list of full path/file names.

The *zipEm()* function takes the file list and destination archive file name and makes a .zip file.

The *Button1_Click()* routine calls the first two routines and provides feedback to the user.

```
        ' returns list of items from column col that are selected
Function selectedList(dgv1 As DataGridView, col As Integer) As List(Of String)
    selectedList = New List(Of String)
    For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In dgv1.SelectedCells
        If cell.ColumnIndex = col Then selectedList.Add(cell.Value.ToString())
    Next
End Function

' archives a list of files to the designated file (overwriting, if it already exists)
Function zipEm(fileList As List(Of String), nzfName As String) As Boolean
    Try
        If File.Exists(nzfName) Then File.Delete(nzfName)
        Using newZipFile As ZipArchive = ZipFile.Open(nzfName, ZipArchiveMode.Create)
            For Each pfn As String In fileList
                newZipFile.CreateEntryFromFile(pfn, Path.GetFileName(pfn))
            Next
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fileList As List(Of String) = selectedList(dgv1, 0)
    If fileList.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("No valid items selected.", vbExclamation, "'lil problem")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim nzfName As String = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileList(0)),
                            "sample (" & fileList.Count.ToString() & " items).zip")
    If zipEm(fileList, nzfName) Then
        MsgBox("Saved zip file containing " & fileList.Count.ToString() & " items.",
               vbOKOnly, "sucess")
    Else
        MsgBox("Unable to save .zip file.", vbExclamation, "'lil problem")
    End If
End Sub
```

If you prefer to accumulate files to the archive (instead of overwriting), the constant "ZipArchiveMode.Create" can be changed to "ZipArchiveMode.Update" in the *ZipFile.Open()* call of the *zipEm()* routine.